# How to make flex box with limit 2 elements per row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I need to make a table which will contain up to 4 divs.
But the divs in that table always should use maximum of avaliable space.
And one one row should contain not more then 2 divs
For instance if table contains 2 divs it should look like this
[image]

If table has 3 divs then like this: [image]

And if contains 4 then it should look like that

[image]

To achieve it i wrote this code:

```
<div
  style={{
    height: '58vh', border: '1px solid #d9d9d9',
    borderRadius: '0px 0px 2px 2px',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  }}
 >
   <div style={{background:'red', flex: 'auto', margin: '5px'}}
   <div style={{background:'green', flex: 'auto', margin: '5px'}}
   <div style={{background:'blue', flex: 'auto', margin: '5px'}}
   <div style={{background:'pink', flex: 'auto', margin: '5px'}}

 </div>
```

But i missing something here.
For 1 div and for 2 divs it works as planned.
But for more..
This is my result for 3 divs
[image]
And for 4 divs
[image]
Can anyone advice me please what should i change in this code?

PS. Please don't judge my unevenly drawn squeres :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another case of a layout that is flexible but limited to 2 columns. In this case, the columns do not have the same width.

Note that this is different from a grid as here you won't need media queries to have a responsive layout (with a grid you would need to switch to a single column at some break point). This layout will change when the columns are of equal length (50/50). The cells will jump and will be placed one under the other. In fact, this layout will work as if you were using container queries, which is even better :-).

[image: just before switch]
[image: after the switch]

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.inner:nth-child(2n+1) {
  flex:1 1 50%;
}
/* right column width
  this can however small or big or omitted */
.inner:nth-child(2n) {
  min-width: 100px;
}

/* just colors and stuff*/
.inner {
  padding:.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.inner:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: lightpink;
}
.inner:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.inner:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.inner:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">one</div>
  <div class="inner">two</div>
  <div class="inner">three</div>
  <div class="inner">four</div>
</div>
```

Note that I used [flex shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property above.

Why does it work you may ask? The first, red column needs 50% of the space and grows if it has more space. The next column (green block) needs 100px. So you already have 50% + 100px. Now comes the next block (blue block) which must be at least 50% wide. 50% + 100px + 50% is greater than 100%, so the blue block is moved to the next row. So the only requirement is that the blocks must be larger than 1px (50% + 1px + 50% is still larger then 100%). Clean and simple.

Answer (score 11):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inner {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.inner:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red;
}

.inner:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: gold;
}

.inner:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: green;
}

.inner:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">one</div>
  <div class="inner">two</div>
  <div class="inner">three</div>
  <div class="inner">four</div>
</div>
```

I used the following steps to achieve your result.

1. Make the container which contains the inner boxes as `flex`.
2. Give the container `flex-wrap: wrap` so that the inner boxes which do not have place on the same line, shift to the next line.
3. Give `flex-basis: 50%` to the inner boxes so that they take up 50% of the available space.
4. Give the inner boxes `flex-grow: 1` so that if the last box has any space left, it will take up all of it.

References:

- [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)
- [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)
- [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)
- [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)
- (Extra) [flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)

*PS: Try commenting the fourth inner box so that the third box will take up the whole horizontal space.*

Comment: Not a problem. Just as a cherry on the cake, the css property [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) is used as a shorthand for `flex-shrink` `flex-grow` `flex-basis`.

Comment: Correction to the above comment: It's actually `flex-grow` `flex-shrink` `flex-basis`.

Answer (score 1):

What you mean about use `Grid` for this?

example:

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
```

here it's guide for Grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: I don't mind using grid but  when there are 3 divs.
Grid doesn't use avaliable empty space

Comment: OP specifically mentions flex box not grid, answer below works fine for OPs purposes.